# How to hide or remove country and city fields from moodle edit profile page?

Tags: moodle

How can I hide or remove country and city fields from moodle edit profile page without touching or hacking core moodle files?

Answer (score 2):

Site Admin menu -> Users -> Permissions -> User Policies

Look for 'Hide user fields'

I think that's what you need - it's a multi-select.